# Error with fi in if then else shell script

Tags: shell, if-statement

There is a shell script with if, then, else. Here is the part of the code, it's not the whole, just the part:

```
DAYOFWEEK=$(date +"%u")
echo $DAYOFWEEK
if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" -eq 1 ]; then
echo "OK. It's Monday. We are running a weekly backup on Mondays."

echo "`date` - Deleting weekly remote backup files."
sftp -oPort=199 $SFTPUSER@$SFTPSITE <<EOF;
    cd user;
    cd weekly;
    ls -al;
    rm *;
    bye;
    EOF;
    echo "DONE"
rsync -ave "ssh -p 199" /root/backups/files/$THESITE/daily/ 
root@coolsite.org:/root/user/weekly
else
 echo "No weekly backups today"
fi
```

I get en error:

```
./backup.sh: 120: ./backup.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

root@developementbox:~/backups#

It doesn't like fi and I don't understand what is wrong with this.

Comment: The terminating `EOF` should not be indented.

Comment: ...or if you want to indent it (and you're using bash), you should change `<<EOF` to `<<-EOF`. Note that this requires you to use tab characters to indent, not spaces. I don't think that you need those semicolons at the end of each statement, by the way.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for answers. They helped me. Unidented EOF and ';' before fi.

Comment: Tom Fenech: That -- especially mentioning the `<<-` option, which many people are not aware of -- should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EOF terminating your sftp commands must start at the beginning of the line and must not be terminated by ;

What is happening is that sftp continues to consume the rest of your shell script including the fi before returning control leaving your if condition unterminated as the fi has been incorrectly treated as an sftp command.

Remove spaces or tabs before EOF and the ; after all of the sftp commands including the EOF terminator and you should be good to go.